# How can I properly align my labels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

More help needed with this little project of mine again, this time trying to get two labels that are inside a panel in certain positions. Those positions being one on the left and then a separation of spaces (like a tab) and then the second label to make way for entries being added below them when a button is pressed which I am also unsure how to start.

I've uploaded an image of the current program running :

[image]

As you can see I have two buttons (may change to one at some point) and then a separate results panel with currently two labels inside that I want to move. I want 'Name' to be on the left side and 'Grade' slightly more to the right (separated by about a tabs worth of space). I'm also unsure what the two little lines are so if someone could explain that to me it would be great.

Where I plan to go with this is then for a button entry to lead to a name entry being entered below these labels and a grade entry being entered below these labels which keeps updating with each button press. If anyone could guide me in the right direction for this it would be great. I have provided the code for the panel below.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField; 

public class GradePanel2 extends JPanel {

private JButton addEntry, calculate;
private JLabel name, grade, nameResult, gradeResult;
private JTextField nameField, gradeField, resultField;

public GradePanel2() {

    // Button to add entry to list
    addEntry = new JButton("Add entry to list");
    addEntry.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    // Button to print all entries in correct format
    calculate = new JButton("Print all user grades");
    calculate.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    //Create Labels
    name = new JLabel("Enter student name: ");
    nameField = new JTextField(10);
    nameField.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    grade = new JLabel("Enter students mark: ");
    gradeField = new JTextField(5);
    gradeField.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    //Result Labels
    nameResult = new JLabel("NAME");
    gradeResult = new JLabel("GRADE");


    //Bottom segment for result
    resultField = new JTextField();
    resultField.setOpaque(false);
    resultField.setEditable(false);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Bottom Panel
    JPanel GradePanel = new JPanel();
        GradePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Students/Results"));
    GradePanel.setOpaque(false);
    GradePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0 , 100));
    GradePanel.add(resultField);
    resultField.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    GradePanel.add(nameResult);
    GradePanel.add(gradeResult);

    //Button Panel
    JPanel ButtonPane = new JPanel();
    ButtonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ButtonPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    addEntry.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    calculate.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    ButtonPane.add(addEntry);
    ButtonPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    ButtonPane.add(calculate);

    //Label Panel
    JPanel labelPane = new JPanel();
    labelPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    labelPane.add(name);
    labelPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (5,0)));
    labelPane.add(nameField);
    labelPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,2)));
    labelPane.add(grade);
    labelPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (5,0)));
    labelPane.add(gradeField);

    //Add all panels to the main panel
    add(labelPane, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(ButtonPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(GradePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
}

public class buttonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String studentName;
        int studentMark;

        studentName = nameField.getText();
        String intMark = gradeField.getText();
        studentMark = Integer.parseInt(intMark);



    }
}

}
```

and then the driver class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Grade2{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grade Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GradePanel2 panel = new GradePanel2();
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
};
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
}}
```

Comment: Is this your full code? Please post your full code so I can edit :)

Comment: @MiaLegaspi Added full code including driver class

Comment: A JTable would be better for your Student Results JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take time to read this the most flexible Layout Manager that commonly used by programmer :)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Btw I separate your class `Bottom Panel` It's a little bit confused while reading it. Much better try the Nested Classes to look your code clean and easy to read.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField; 

public class GradePanel2 extends JPanel {

private JButton addEntry, calculate;
private JLabel name, grade, nameResult, gradeResult;
private JTextField nameField, gradeField, resultField;

public GradePanel2() {

    // Button to add entry to list
    addEntry = new JButton("Add entry to list");
    addEntry.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    // Button to print all entries in correct format
    calculate = new JButton("Print all user grades");
    calculate.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    //Create Labels
    name = new JLabel("Enter student name: ");
    nameField = new JTextField(10);
    nameField.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    grade = new JLabel("Enter students mark: ");
    gradeField = new JTextField(5);
    gradeField.addActionListener(new buttonListener());


    //Bottom segment for result
    resultField = new JTextField();
    resultField.setOpaque(false);
    resultField.setEditable(false);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    GridBagConstraints nameResultConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();//Constraints
    GridBagConstraints gradeResultConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();//Constraints


    //Button Panel
    JPanel ButtonPane = new JPanel();
    ButtonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ButtonPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    addEntry.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    calculate.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    ButtonPane.add(addEntry);
    ButtonPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    ButtonPane.add(calculate);

    //Label Panel
    JPanel labelPane = new JPanel();
    labelPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labelPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    labelPane.add(name);
    labelPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (5,0)));
    labelPane.add(nameField);
    labelPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,2)));
    labelPane.add(grade);
    labelPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (5,0)));
    labelPane.add(gradeField);

    myBottomPanel mybottompanel = new myBottomPanel();//Object

    //Add all panels to the main panel
    add(labelPane, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(ButtonPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(mybottompanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
}

public class myBottomPanel extends JPanel{
    public myBottomPanel()
    {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //Result Labels
         nameResult = new JLabel("NAME");
         gradeResult = new JLabel("GRADE");

         //Constraints
        GridBagConstraints nameResultConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints gradeResultConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Bottom Panel
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Students/Results"));
        setOpaque(false);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0 , 100));

        nameResultConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        nameResultConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        nameResultConstraints.weighty = 0.5;

        add(nameResult,nameResultConstraints);
        add(gradeResult);

    }
}
public class buttonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        String studentName;
        int studentMark;

        studentName = nameField.getText();
        String intMark = gradeField.getText();
        studentMark = Integer.parseInt(intMark);



    }
}

}
```

and here is your Frame.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Grade2{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grade Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GradePanel2 panel = new GradePanel2();
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
};
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
}}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, learning by example always works well with me. Appreciate the time

Comment: @SkyPlus You're always welcome :) Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want data displayed in a column then you need to use an appropriate layout manager to achieve the effect you want.

Maybe you can use a `GridBagLayout`. You can have columns and spaces between the columns, but you need to use the appropriate constraints. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and working examples.

However, the easier option would be to use a JTable which is a component designed for display data in rows/columns. Again check out the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Going to look into tables right now!